# gnuplot palette for splot 3D surface of errors: symmetrical colors

Tags: plot, 3d, gnuplot, surface, color-palette

I am plotting a 3D surface (I have z values on a matrix 8x10 in a text file); The z values represent the error, so it goes e.g. from -20% to +10%. I would like to plot this with colors, in a symmetric way, meaning e.g. -10% needs to be the same red intensity as +10%. The value around 0% (very small errors) needs to be green (or also blue or whatever). So in this way the more intense the red is, the greater the error is (regardless if positive or negative).
I am plotting using:

```
# line styles
set style line 1 lc rgb '#B2182B' # red
set style line 2 lc rgb '#D6604D' # red-orange
set style line 3 lc rgb '#F4A582' # 
set style line 4 lc rgb '#FDDBC7' # pale orange
set style line 5 lc rgb '#D1E5F0' # pale blue
set style line 6 lc rgb '#92C5DE' # 
set style line 7 lc rgb '#4393C3' # medium blue
set style line 8 lc rgb '#2166AC' # dark blue
# palette
set palette defined ( 0 '#B2182B',\
                      1 '#D6604D',\
              2 '#F4A582',\
              3 '#FDDBC7',\
              4 '#D1E5F0',\
              5 '#92C5DE',\
              6 '#4393C3',\
              7 '#2166AC' )
set dgrid3d 30,30 gauss 1
splot 'file.csv' matrix using 1:2:3 with lines palette title 'Error (%)'
```

I took the line styles and palette from ColorBrewer RdBu.
I tried also centering around zero using `stats` and `set cbrange` but without success.

Answer (score 0):

"without success" is not sufficient description to debug.  It should work to give the desired symmetric range as `set cbrange [-foo : foo]".  The numeric values given in the` set palette` command are not important so long as they are symmetric. Here is an example

```
set palette defined (-1 "dark-red", 0 "grey90", 1 "dark-red")
set cbrange [-15 : 15]
set xyplane at 0
splot besj0(y)*x*x with pm3d
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ethan, it worked! I did this:

`stats 'file.csv' matrix using 3 nooutput` \\

`cb_val = (abs(STATS_min - 0) < abs(STATS_max - 0) ? abs(STATS_max - 0) : abs(STATS_min - 0))` \\

`set cbrange [0 - cb_val : 0 + cb_val]` \\

`set palette defined (-cb_val 'dark-red', -cb_val+STATS_stddev '#D6604D', -cb_val+2.0*STATS_stddev '#FDDBC7', -cb_val+3.0*STATS_stddev '#4393C3', 0 '#2166AC', +cb_val-3.0*STATS_stddev '#4393C3', +cb_val-2.0*STATS_stddev '#FDDBC7', +cb_val-STATS_stddev '#D6604D', cb_val 'dark-red')` \\

`splot 'file.csv' matrix using 1:2:3 with lines palette title 'Error (%)'`